# U-boot environment is not the same as Linux "fw_printenv"

Tags: yocto, u-boot, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I've build an image for my Jetson Nano with yocto using the meta-tegra layer.

This build is using u-boot as bootloader which is set to save the environment on an MMC partition (mmcblk0p14).

`gdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` shows the following:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
...
  14        20996096        20998143   1024.0 KiB  8300  UBOOTENV
...
```

And the sector size is 512.

I've then configured `u-boot-tegra/include/configs/p3450-porg.h` with:

```
...
/* Env is located in it's own partition */
#define CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_MMC
#define CONFIG_SYS_MMC_ENV_DEV      1
#define CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET       (20996096 * 512)
...
```

Where `CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET` = Start_Sector * Block_Size

This works fine (as far as I can see) as the environment is saved successfully to MMC when i use `saveenv`.

However, the environment i get when i print it in u-boot shell is NOT the same as when i print the environment with `fw_printenv` u-boot tool. I have set the `/etc/fw_env.config` to:

```
# Device name   Device offset   Env size
/dev/mmcblk0p14       0          0x2000
```

So what I've gathered is that, either the `fw_env.config` is set wrong or the u-boot environment is saved somewhere else on the MMC and no the partition 14.

Does anyone have suggestions to what i could try?

*****************************************************EDIT:*****************************************************

Doing `dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p14 of=tmp.txt` and reading the tmp.txt file shows the environment that the `fw_printenv` shows and not the environment I'm seeing in u-boot shell.

So something must be wrong in the `u-boot-tegra/include/configs/p3450-porg.h` configuration. I just wonder where it actually writes the environment to when i do a `saveenv`...

Any Idea what I can try to change?

Comment: Can you please include the full console log from power on until 'printenv' in U-Boot?  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide the console log right now as I'm trying a new partition scheme on the same SD-card. From the maintainer of the meta-tegra layer: "_Looking at the U-Boot source (common/env_mmc.c), the offset is a 32-bit unsigned integer, so any offset over 4GiB isn't going to work very well._" So with that said, I'm attempting to build a new image with the uboot partition as p1 instead of p14 and retrying. If the problem still persists i will update the question with the full console log. Thank you!

Comment: It appears this was in fact the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments to the question, the offset is a 32-bit integer so attempting to give it the value of more than 4,294,967,295 (which 20996096 * 512 is) is not gonna work.

To fix it, I've rearranged my partition scheme to have my uboot environment partition as partition 1 instead of 14 and changed the `fw_env.config` and `p3450-porg.h` patch accordingly.